# mysql sort string max length

Tags: mariadb

I got problem with sorting large strings in mysql. For example ORDER BY with string with length of VARCHAR(1000) does no effect. Butt at length of VACHAR(100) it works fine.

I using 10.5.17-MariaDB.

May be exist inner mysql variable that limits sorting length.

Comment: [The manual](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/mdb/system-variables/max_sort_length/) has information on this,

Comment: Great! Can I change its value by query?

Comment: Try `SET SESSION max_sort_length = <number>` before running your query

Comment: thanks, may be you create full answer, i will accept it for future generations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regards to RiggsFolly and Raymond Nijland, here is the answer for my question:

Just need to add `SET SESSION max_sort_length = <number>`  before runing query, for example:

```
SET SESSION max_sort_length = 1000;
```